# Should unrelated context be stored separately when using the React Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, state-management

I am building a web app that requires several pieces of state to be stored in context as they are required globally. For this, I am using the React Context API (instead of Redux).

I have a **store** folder that is a sibling to my **components** folder, within which I currently have one file storing my `loggedIn` state. I am now in the position where I want to add additional elements of context (current language, user XP etc.).

What is the best practice for storing these elements?

- Ideally, I would store it in the same file (and preferably the same object) as the `loggedIn` state and utilise the same provider, using a reducer to selectively update the state.
- However, I have seen others create individual, separate files for each unrelated piece of context. In my mind, this seems inefficient as it requires the inclusion of extra providers, additional imports, and more boilerplate code. Is it not better to just have a single, centralised context provider?

What are the advantages and drawbacks of each approach?

(*If this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, let me know and I'll delete it*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that any time the value of a context changes, every component that consumes that context must rerender. So if you have a single monolithic context, with a large object as its value, then changes to one part of the object will force rerenders of components that only care about different parts of the object.

For that reason, having a single context can be a performance problem. One way to mitigate this is to split it up into smaller contexts, each focused on a single area. If that smaller context value changes, then the consumers of that context will still need to rerender, but that's probably desired since those components are very likely to care about the change.

Comment: Thank you, that is not something I had considered. This is particularly relevant for the ```userXP``` state as it updates regularly so it would be unwise to combine that with the ```loggedIn``` state, which necessarily re-renders the entire DOM.